# Woocommerce вставить товары в OwlCarousel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как можно вывести последние добавленные, самые популярные и товары со скидкой в Woocommerce в виде разных каруселей OwlCarousel2 на одной страницу, желательно без плагина.

Answer (score 0):

В документации OwlCarousel2 на github написано:

**Использование**

Оберните ваши элементы (div, a, img, span, li и т.п.) в контейнер (div, ul и т.п.). Для применения правильных стилей требуется только класс owl-carousel:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <li class="product..."> Товар </div>
  <li class="product..."> Товар </div>
  <li class="product..."> Товар </div>
  <li class="product..."> Товар </div>
  <li class="product..."> Товар </div>
</div>
```

**Замечание**: owl-theme класс опционален, но без него вам придется стилизовать навигацию самостоятельно.

Вызовите плагин и карусель готова.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```